# Grouping in mysql with lower value from other column

Tags: mysql

Need group by on `id` and `group` and max of `tval` and lower of group if tval has duplicate/repeating values. Appreciate your help.

| id | timel | group | tval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | a | 1.184 |
| 3 | 0.5 | a | 2.173 |
| 3 | 1 | a | 1.065 |
| 3 | 3 | a | 1.143 |
| 3 | 6 | a | 3.222 |
| 3 | 9 | a | 1.851 |
| 3 | 12 | a | 3.222 |
| 4 | 0 | a | 1.184 |
| 4 | 0.5 | a | 2.173 |
| 4 | 1 | a | 1.065 |
| 4 | 3 | a | 1.143 |
| 4 | 0.7 | a | 2.322 |
| 4 | 9 | a | 1.851 |
| 4 | 12 | a | 1.345 |

Expected output

| id | group | timel | tval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a | 6 | 3.222 |
| 4 | a | 0.7 | 2.322 |

Here is the create and inserts query for those who are interested to try it out.

```
CREATE TABLE sample (id INT, timel DOUBLE, group VARCHAR(50), tval DOUBLE);

INSERT INTO sample VALUES
(3,0,'a',1.184),
(3,0.5,'a',2.173),
(3,1,'a',1.065),
(3,3,'a',1.143),
(3,6,'a',3.222),
(3,9,'a',1.851),
(3,12,'a',3.222),
(4,0,'a',1.184),
(4,0.5,'a',2.173),
(4,1,'a',1.065),
(4,3,'a',1.143),
(4,0.7,'a',2.322),
(4,9,'a',1.851),
(4,12,'a',1.345);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to filter the table, so that you get only the rows with the max `tval` for each combination of `id` and `group` and then agregate to get the min `timel`:

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.trt, MIN(timel) timel, s1.tval 
FROM sample s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM sample s2
  WHERE  s2.id = s1.id AND s2.trt = s1.trt AND s2.tval > s1.tval
)
GROUP BY s1.id, s1.trt, s1.tval
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT id, trt, timel, tval 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, trt ORDER BY tval DESC, timel) rn
  FROM sample
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a16d47f177ad71805604c76ab38c521d).